# Passing Empty Array/Multiple Integers To Function And Returning Them

Tags: c#, arrays

Lets say I have array (array[20]) and I want to pass it to function which will fill it with random numbers and return it.

How do I pass an empty array to function and how do I return it after function is done?

Also, lets assume I have 3 different integers ( int a = 3; int b = 2; int c = 5;)

How do I pass all 3 integers to function and return them after function is done?

I've just started learning functions, and so far I only know how to pass 2 different integers and return one.
I know exactly what to write into functions, but I just don't know how to pass the variables/empty array.

Comment: I think you're a little off-track regarding passing empty variables  into functions. You *can* do that, but you don't usually need to. Try to design functions so that they return a single value.

Answer (score 1):

An array is a reference type, so you just pass it and modify it. The changes (other than assigning the variable) will propagate to the caller:

```
private void MyFunc(int[] array)
{
   //Some generation
   array[0] = 1; //Generated by fair dice roll
                 //Guaranteed to be random
}
```

For the integers, you need to actually pass by `ref` for changes to get back to the caller. You can't return more than one value, so you either pass by `ref`, return them as a `Tuple` or return a custom class. Given your experience level, you probably want the `ref` option:

```
private void MyFunc2(ref int i, ref int j, ref int k)
{
   i = 3;
   j = 4;
   k = 5;
}

MyFunc2(ref var1, ref var2, ref var3);
```

You *normally* don't do this, so consider your use case carefully.

Documentation for ref: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you want to do this, but anyway...

`How do I pass an empty array to function and how do I return it after function is done?`

Simply return the same parameter after doing the job:

```
int[] emptyArr = new int[20];
yourFunction(emptyArr);

int[] yourFunction(int[] arr) {

  //Do your work
  return arr; 
}
```

Note that you don't even need to `return arr`, neither declare the funcion as `int[]`, since whatever you do with the `arr` variable will affect the `emptyArr`. It's a reference.

In C# there are references and values. `int[]` is a reference. Check it out: http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx

`How do I pass all 3 integers to function and return them after function is done?`

```
void numbers( ref int a, ref int b, ref int c) { //do your thing here }
```

You shouldn't write `ref int a, ref int b, ref int c`, you will learn someday about side-effects and application state in functional programming. But anyway, it's OK for learning.

Answer (score 0):

The array will be passed by reference so you can pass it in and fill it and simply return.

To return the three int values you can pass them by reference, [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx), or you can also set up a set of integer to return the value in and flag them as [out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx). Using `out` passes the values of the original data and forces you to set the values of the referenced returned integers.

```
    static void passInts(ref int a, ref int b, ref int c)
    {
        a = a + b;
        b = b + c;
        c = c + 2;
    }
    static void passInts(int a, int b, int c, out int a1, out int b1, out int c1)
    {
        a1 = a + b;
        b1 = b + c;
        c1 = c + 2;
    }


        int a = 1; 
        int b = 2; 
        int c= 3;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("a={0}, b={1}, c={2}", a, b, c));
        passInts(ref a, ref b, ref c);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("a={0}, b={1}, c={2}", a, b, c));
        int A,B,C;
        passInts(a, b, c, out A, out B, out C);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("a={0}, b={1}, c={2}", A,B,C));
```